# Cannot Shorten Long Dynamic Link

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to generate a shorten dynamic link from a long dynamic link

I followed the steps shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/unity/create

yet I get the same long URL when shortening process is completed.

```
public void CreateInviteLink()
{
    var components = new Firebase.DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkComponents(
        // The base Link.
        new System.Uri("https://myapp.com"),
        // The dynamic link URI prefix.
        "https://myapp.page.link")
        {
            IOSParameters = new Firebase.DynamicLinks.IOSParameters("com.myapp.myapp"),
            AndroidParameters = new Firebase.DynamicLinks.AndroidParameters("com.myapp.myApp"),
        };

    Debug.Log("Long Dynamic Link: " + components.LongDynamicLink);

    var options = new Firebase.DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkOptions
    {
        PathLength = DynamicLinkPathLength.Unguessable
    };

    Firebase.DynamicLinks.DynamicLinks.GetShortLinkAsync(components, options).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("GetShortLinkAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("GetShortLinkAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        // Short Link has been created.
        Firebase.DynamicLinks.ShortDynamicLink link = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("Generated Short Dynamic Link: {0}", link.Url);

        text.text = link.Url.ToString();

        var warnings = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(link.Warnings);
        if (warnings.Count > 0)
        {
            // Debug logging for warnings generating the short link.
        }

    });
    
}
```

result Logs

Long Dynamic Link: https://myapp.page.link/?afl=&amv=0&apn=com.myapp.myApp&ibi=com.myapp.myapp&ifl=&ipfl=&link=https://myapp.com
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Generated Short Dynamic Link: https://myapp.page.link/?afl=&amv=0&apn=com.myapp.myApp&ibi=com.myapp.myapp&ifl=&ipfl=&link=https://myapp.com
UnityEngine.Debug:LogFormat(String, Object[])

## **EDIT:**

### How I did it:

You can't shorten dynamic links with Firebase SDK in the editor but I used [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest) and UnityWebRequest for testing short links inside the editor and it worked

```
IEnumerator HTTPRequestShortLink(string longDynamicLink)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("longDynamicLink", longDynamicLink);

    // trigger of function is HTTP request. this link is the trigger for that func
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]", form);

    //for getting response
    www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete! " + www.GetResponseHeader("response"));
        string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
        
        // Parse returned json 
        parsedJsonObject obj = parsedJsonObject.CreateFromJSON(responseText);
        Debug.Log("shortLink: " + obj.shortLink);
        Debug.Log("HTTP Response text: " + responseText);

    }
}
```